# wrong output after strcat in xv6

Tags: c, xv6

I am trying make a function that reads txt.file line by line and save in to char pointer array by each index for each line.

As Xv6 environment do not have any `strcat`, or any typical STL library. I created strcat function from scratch.

For this algoritm the reason I put `sizeof(buf[0])` is to read letter by letter as it spits out letter by letter when it is on the loop.

I successfully managed to extract letter by letter and tried to add the pointer array of buffer 2. The index of the array only moves when it see the line changes and update the `index=counter++`.

However, when I tried to do string concat with str(buff2,buff) and print out buffer2 by index.
the outcome comes out as

```
-buff2 0: NNNNNNNNNNn  
-buff2 1: NNNNNNNNNn 
-buff2 2: NNNNNNNNn 
-buff2 3: NNNNNNNn 
-buff2 4 : NNNNNNn 
-buff2 5: NNNNNn 
-buff2 6: NNNNn 
-buff2 7: NNNn 
-buff2 8: NNn 
-buff2 9 : Nn 
-buff2 10: n
```

txt file contains

```
no.1 \next line
no.3 \next line
no.5 \next line
no.6 \next line
no.7 \next line
......
```

```
#include "types.h"
#include "stat.h"
#include "user.h"

char *starCat(char *a,char *b){
 int i=0, j=0; 
 int cont=0;
 int len=strlen(a)+strlen(b);
 char *combined;
  combined=(char*)malloc(len*sizeof(char));

    for(i=0;i<strlen(a);i++){
        combined[i]=a[i];
    }

    for(j=i;j<strlen(a)+strlen(b);j++){
       combined[j]=b[cont++];
    }

 combined[len]='\0';
    return combined;
}

char buf[100];

void
trial(int fd, char *name)
{
   int n, i=0, count=0, count2=0,l,g;
   char *buff2;
 
  buff2=malloc(512*sizeof(char*));
  while((n = read(fd, buf, sizeof(buf[g]))) > 0){
    
    for(i=0; i<n; i++){
      count++;
    
      if(buf[i] == '\n'){
    buff2[count2]=*starCat(&buff2[count2], &buf[i]);
        l++;
    count2++;
    }
      else {   
    printf(1,"buf1 value: %s",&buf[i]);//shows the individual char for 
    buff2[count2]=*starCat(&buff2[count2], &buf[i]);
    
      }
         printf(1,"\n");
    
    }    
        
  }
    if(n < 0){
      printf(1, "uniqtrial: read error\n");
      exit();
    }

 printf(1,"\n");
 
int t;
for(t=0;t<count2;t++){
    printf(1,"buff2: %s \n", &buff2[t]);
}
    
    
}
```

Comment: You remember that strings in C are null-terminated, but you forget to allocate space for it. You also have problem with the arguments you pass to your `strCat` function, are you sure that `&buff2[count2]` is a pointer to the first character of a *null-terminate* string? And `*strCat(...)` will only get the first character, and disregard the pointer you return (leading to a memory leak). *And* your `strCat` doesn't follow the semantics of the standard C `strcat` function (which uses the first argument as the *destination* string).

Comment: Your buffer assigned to `combined` don't have room for terminating null-character while you are trying to add that. Allocate one more element.

Comment: `sizeof(buf[g])` is `sizeof(char)`, which is `1`. Is this really what you want?

Comment: Other part of `trial` also looks weird. It seems you are confusing "a pointer to strings (character arrays)" and "a pointer to pointers to strings".